# rendering different data values inside an ejs 'Scriptlet' tag

Tags: ejs

I'm kind of new to ejs ,I have been working on this ejs project we're part of my code involves me having to create a for statement which will loop through data in an object "data1" which is nested together  with "data2"  as follows

Data 1: `var data1 = <%='some data'%>` and

Data 2: `var data2 = <%='second data'%>`.

The code :

```
<% for (var i in data2.data1) {%>
 "some action"
   <%}%>
Problem is data2 is not being rendered when you include in the ejs 'Scriptlet' tag <%   %>
```

Full code :

```
<html>
<body>

<table id="customers">
 <tr>
   <th align="center">
     <% var clss = d2.className  %>
      <%   for (var i in data[0].classes.clss.Monday
        ) {%>
         <% var object = data[0].classes.clss.Monday
            %>
               <%  if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) { %>
               <th><%- object[i][0]  %></th>
                 <%}%>
                  <%}%>

                  </th>

                 </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide us wih more information

Comment: ok, so im trying to create an ejs timetable which will render data based on a person's class. The data is stored in a mongodb database as nested objects.I have two data sets one is the data containing the subjects, times and teacher. the other is just data containing the class of the person, so my code will have a For in loop which will use the "hasOwnProperty". everything works  if i manualy put a classroom room number : <% var object = data[0].classes.Form1A.Monday
 %> but if i use a classroom number from the database it refuses

Comment: Ah, try it with <%- 'second data'%>.

Comment: still nothing, even tried <%   firstData.<%=secondData%>  %>